# jquery structure - one function per file

Tags: javascript

I am primarily a c# programmer.  I have recently been getting into some jquery development.  when I am working on applications in c#, I create a new class file (.cs) for every new class that I create.

How do people generally structure their jquery/javascript applications.  I would like to reuse some functionality across pages, so do I put each function in it's own .js file?  or is it best practice to group like functions into files?  I can't see putting each on in it's own file as that would create many calls to import individual file into a page....

How are other people handling these types of situations.
Thanks for any thoughts.

EDIT - I should have mentioned that I am beginning to look at unit testing with QUnit and figured it would be good to have proper structure of my project to better facilitate unit testing.

Comment: The common practice is to consolidate them all in one file and do the work on a separate file. In client side development you want to create the minimum amount of request possible, for a faster website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally keep all plugins into their perspective files but functions I create I tend to place into a "global.js" file that the entire site will pull from. Then I don't have to worry about pulling in specific files when a need a specific function. It will  all be in the global.

Answer (score 4):

If you DO put them all in separate files, you would want to have a build script that combines and minimizes them into a single one (or just a few) so you do not have 500 Javascript files to download to your browser.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest putting your common functionalities to a util.js file and then arrange your javascript codes according to functionality.

However it is not a good practice to have lots of js files included in every page, thus you might consider combinin the files into a single file and minifying that final js file. this way you would have optimized your final product while being able to unit test functionalities separately.

Answer (score 0):

Put it all in one file. Multiple HTTP requests are more expensive than big files, plus you're assured that the file containing the function you need is already loaded.